# What is the use of implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

What is the use of implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, when the below code is working just fine without it?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Color" 
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Color}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Colors}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Colors}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button Content="Change Colors" Click="Change"/>

   public class Data
   {
      private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
      public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
      {
         get { return _items; }

      }

      public Data()
      {
         _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
         _items.Add(new Item() { Name = "A" });
         _items.Add(new Item() { Name = "B" });
      }

      public void Change()
      {
         _items[0].Colors.RemoveAt(1);
      }
   }

   public class Item
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Color { get; set; }


      private IList<string> _colors;
      public IList<string> Colors
      {
         get { return _colors; }
      }


      public Item()
      {
         _colors = new List<string> { "Green", "Blue" };
         Color = _colors[0];
      }
   }
```

Comment: To notify when a property changes. For static data, it is indeed useless. FYI, ObservableCollection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so it works out of the box when its data changes.

Comment: Now try to change your data after it's loaded, and see if the UI shows that change

Comment: `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Pikoh That is what Change button is doing! And the combobox is getting updated without INPC.

Comment: @Kilazur Oh I suspected that!

Comment: As @Equalsk and Kilazur has already said, ObservableCollection implements InotifyPropertyChanged out of the box

Comment: Thanks all! Then what if I want to have a custom functionality when the collection changes! For example throw a message! Should I use List instead of ObservableCollection  and throw that message in the property's `´set´?

Comment: The you could handle the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection<T>. I added this to my answer.

Comment: Actually, some people do make their ObservableCollection properties implement INPC, which is worthless.  OC properties should be read only, as in your code.  I *think* you may have been asking about that, but it wasn't clear, and it may have resulted in the downvotes.  If I am correct, let me know and I'll help clear up your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection<T>` implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces so if you simply want to be able to add and remove items from the source collection at runtime there is no need for you to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

You would have to implement it in your custom `Item` class if you wanted to be able to for example update the `Name` or `Color` property dynamically though.

If you set the `Name` property of an `Item` to a new value this won't get reflected in the view unless the `Item` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the Name property.

> What if I want to have a custom functionality when the collection changes! For example throw a message! Should I use List instead of ObservableCollection and throw that message in the property's `´set´?

The you could handle the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection<T>`.